# Syntax error in insert into statement in C#. While inserting the values to access

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, ms-access

i write code that insert some data into Microsoft Access database but i have an error "Syntax error in insert into statement" i don't know why !!!Please help me. thanks Advance

[image]
Its showing below error[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the space in the column name, I think you need to delimit the "Book Name" identifier with square brackets, i.e.:

```
insert into book ([Book Name],Description)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Remove ; and put BookName instead of book name

```
oleDbCmd.CommandText = "insert into book (BookName,Description) values ('" +textBookName.Text+ "','" +textDescription.Text+ "')";
```